# couchDB no result searching the DB with curl

Tags: curl, couchdb, pouchdb

I don't understand why `query` in javascript returns a result whereas the curl command doesn't :

```
usersDatabase.query(mapByEmail, {
                key: email,
                include_docs: true
            }).then(function (result) {

                if (!result.rows.length) { //email doesn't exist in DB
                    return callback(false);
                }
                if (result.rows.length === 1) {
                    return callback(result);
                }
                console.log("problem : several docs in the DB with same email, run a duplicate check on the DB");
                return callback(result);
            });
```

which outputs a big JSON result in the console of my app.

Wheras curl:

```
    $ curl -u id:pass https://louis.cloudant.com/boardline_users/_design/views/_view/email?key="louisr@yahoo.fr"'
```

outputs:

```
{"total_rows":5713,"offset":5713,"rows":[
```

]}

Comment: In the "big JSON", is your key "louisr@yahoo.fr" in there?

Comment: yes ! (sorry for late reply)

Answer (score 0):

The offset in your result is a clear indication that their is nothing to send your back.
So maybe your query is not correctly formatted.

try

curl -X GET -g 'http://id:pass@louis.cloudant.com/boardline_users/_design/views/_view/email?key="louisr@yahoo.fr"'

Answer (score 0):

The curl command you pasted is missing a single quote at the beginning of the URL.

As an alternative to using single quotes, you could escape double quotes:

> $ curl -u id:pass
>   **"**https://louis.cloudant.com/boardline_users/_design/views/_view/email?key=\"louisr@yahoo.fr\"**"**